# Amarok 2.9.0 does not recognize CD drive Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, kubuntu, 18.04, cd, amarok

I am aware that 18.04 has changed the default music player to VLC and not Amarok, but I was hoping perhaps that somebody might know something about it nonetheless.

So when I try to run my funky fresh Kamaal the Abstract CD on Amarok (and rip it for my personal use as well ) I see this:
[image: Amarok Audio CD says it has 0 tracks]
However, the CD functionality works perfectly fine on VLC, K3b (which I ended up having to use to rip it in the end), Brasero, etc. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Amarok plus the kio-audio-cd dependencies. too. Here's what it looks like in the terminal when I try to open the CD

```
`myusername@myusername-MS-7693:~$ amarok
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
amarok(2907)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
amarok(2907)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
Could not parse stylesheet of widget 0x5563d3e9dc20
********************************************************************************************** 
** AMAROK WAS STARTED IN NORMAL MODE. IF YOU WANT TO SEE DEBUGGING INFORMATION, PLEASE USE: ** 
** amarok --debug                                                                           ** 
********************************************************************************************** 
skyroz666saile@skyroz666saile-MS-7693:~$ amarok(2907): couldn't create slave: "Unable to create io-slave:
klauncher said: Unknown protocol 'audiocd'. ...(continues)
```

Does anybody have any ideas in regard to this?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in Amarok itself, which was already reported.

You can track its progress here: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=378183

They seem to know what causes it, but it's not mentioned there at the moment.